Task.WhenAll vs Parallel.ForEachAsync - Which approach is best and why?
I am trying to gain understanding of Threading and Task Parallel Library in .NET. So I was experimenting with running tasks concurrently using 2 approaches as can be seen below.
Some background: I have got list of 5000 photos from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos endpoint and I want to download those photos(being discarded but essentially mimics downloading). I am trying to do this using different approaches and figure out time taken by each approach and why.

First approach, which is sequential, downloads one photo after another and takes longest (approx 24 minutes). This is understandable since I am awaiting to complete download of previous photo until next one begins. So no complaints here.

Second approach uses List<Task> and adds each photo download task to the list and finally awaits for all tasks to complete. This takes approx 1 minute 7 seconds. Since it's downloading multiple photos parallelly, so was expecting lesser time compared to first i.e. sequential approach and it is the case.
.

Third approach uses Parallel.ForEachAsync(). To my surprise, this took 5 minutes 19 seconds to download all photos. I was expecting this to perform similar to the second approach however that's not the case.


using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.Json;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var photosResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
var content = await photosResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var photos = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Photo>>(content, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
})!;

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

// // 1.Sequential - Time taken: 23m 58s
// foreach (var photo in photos)
// {
//     Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {photo.Id} on Thread {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
//     var imageResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(photo.Url);
//     _ = await imageResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
//     Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {photo.Id} on Thread {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
// }

// 2.Tasks - Time taken: 1m 7s
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var photo in photos!)
{
    tasks.Add(DownloadPhotoTask(photo, httpClient));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// // 3.Parallel.ForEach - Time taken: 5m 19s
// await Parallel.ForEachAsync(photos, (photo, _) => DownloadPhotoValueTask(photo, httpClient));

stopwatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Time elapsed: {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
return;


async Task DownloadPhotoTask(Photo photo, HttpClient httpClientInternal)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {photo.Id} on Thread {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
    var imageResponse = await httpClientInternal.GetAsync(photo.Url);
    _ = await imageResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {photo.Id} on Thread {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
}

async ValueTask DownloadPhotoValueTask(Photo photo, HttpClient httpClientInternal)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {photo.Id} on Thread {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
    var imageResponse = await httpClientInternal.GetAsync(photo.Url);
    _ = await imageResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {photo.Id} on Thread {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
}
public record Photo(int Id, string Title, string Url);

What is the significant difference between time taken by 2nd approach and 3rd approach? Which is better? If duration is the only parameter, then obviously from my test, 2nd comes out as the best approach. If it is, why do we need Parallel.ForEachAsync()?
I am also interested to learn more about the internal workings of 2nd and 3rd approaches.

Parallel.ForEachAsync() has a max # of threads, I think

Parallel.ForEachAsync() tries to balance the work to be efficient with used resources, so you're not really comparing apples to apples here. By default max degree of parallelism is set to CPU core count of the environment, so it's not simply running all the tasks at once and await their completion, it's using N threads to perform all the work, where N is environment CPU core count. Have in mind it doesn't have to be the same 4 threads all the time, just at most some 4 threads at any given time of the operation.

@roten what are your sources about "Parallel.ForEachAsync() tries to balance the work to be efficient with used resources"? Is it a book, the official documentation, or personal experimentation? Please consider posting an answer that contains both your claims, and the evidence that supports them, so that it can be evaluated (voted) accordingly by the community. The comments are intended for clarifying the question, not for answering it.

Related: Is Parallel.ForEachAsync a replacement to a plain for loop + append to task list (async await Task.Run)+ WhenAll?

Approach 1 is the kindest to the remote web server; please behave responsibly when requesting other people's resources do something for you

@TheodorZoulias I though a comments are not formalised like answers are, apparently I was wrong, so sorry about it. The knowledge is coming from discussion on github dotnet repository on ForEachAsync() and from the implementation you can see here: https://source.dot.net/#System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs,1df06ef0e843db38

@roten I have studied extensively the source code of the ForEachAsync. There is nothing in the source code indicating that the API does any form of balancing, or takes decisions based on the availability of resources. It's a simple mechanism that spawns tasks in respect to the MaxDegreeOfParallelism policy, and these tasks invoke the body repeatedly until the source is emptied. Wherever you read this information, it's urban legend.

@TheodorZoulias I was not precise with my tries to balance the work to be efficient with used resources. I meant it executes passed work using a (by default) limited number of threads borrowed from the thread pool, so it's more conservative on used threads then run all and let the pool handle the rest. Threads are resources too. It's the passed work that is balanced to handle it with restricted resources, not the other way around.

@roten what you said originally can be interpreted in multiple ways, and that's why posting answers in the comments is not a good idea. Unfortunately there are some older members of the community that are doing it systematically, giving a bad example to the newer members. And the company doesn't want to enforce its own rules, by letting the moderators remove these comments. I have flagged lots of answering comments in the past, and all my flags were declined.

@TheodorZoulias You're right, thank you for putting effort into making SO a better place for all the users, I appreciate that.

The Parallel.ForEachAsync has the option to limit the degree of parallelism, and this option is set by default to Environment.ProcessorCount for this method (source code). If you want to download the images with unlimited parallelism, risking to be perceived as a DOS attacker and be blocked by the remote server, you can set this option to Int32.MaxValue:
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.MaxValue
};

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(photos, parallelOptions, async (photo, cancellationToken) =>
{
    await DownloadPhotoValueTask(photo, httpClient);
});

This way the DownloadPhotoValueTask will be invoked on ThreadPool threads, using all the threads available in the ThreadPool. No limitation will be imposed on how many asynchronous operations will be concurrently in flight. My expectation is that the performance of this approach will be very similar with your 2nd approach (the Task.WhenAll). Creating the tasks in parallel shouldn't make much of a difference compared to creating them on a single thread. The HttpClient APIs are not known to do extensive use of the CPU, so all the DownloadPhotoValueTask tasks should be created almost instantly either way.
To answer directly your questions:

What is the significant difference between time taken by 2nd approach and 3rd approach?

The 3rd approach limits the level of concurrency, while the 2nd is not.

Which is better?

If the speed of the downloading is the only criterion, both are equally good (after configuring the Parallel.ForEachAsync according to the requirements).

Why do we need Parallel.ForEachAsync?

For many reasons:

We want to limit the number of concurrent requests to remote servers, in order to not trigger their anti-DOS defensive mechanisms.
We want to limit the number of tasks that are concurrently in-flight, because each task consumes resources like memory, and too many active tasks could crash our process with an OutOfMemoryException.

You can find more reasons in this related question.
As a side note, you are advised to pass the cancellationToken argument to the APIs HttpClient.GetAsync and HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync, to get more responsive completion of the parallel loop in case of an error.

You don't need an unlimited amount of threads to start all of the downloads at once. That's the whole purpose of async.

@Blindy the Parallel.ForEachAsync has a single setting that controls both the maximum degree of parallelism and the maximum level of concurrency. You can't configure these two settings independently with this API. So if you want unlimited concurrency, as the OP wants, you must have unlimited parallelism as well. In practice the synchronous work of the DownloadPhotoValueTask should be pretty minuscule, so I don't expect too many threads to be involved in the downloading process.

And I'm telling you that you don't need any additional threads to run an unlimited amount of http requests. Which you should know, because his #2 example does exactly this.

@Blindy my answer shows how to use the Parallel.ForEachAsync API in order to do asynchronous work both parallelly and concurrently, with unlimited concurrency, and with parallelism limited only to the ThreadPool availability. My expectation is that by configuring the Parallel.ForEachAsync with MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.MaxValue, the performance of downloading the images will be identical with the 2nd OP's approach (the Task.WhenAll). Which hopefully will help the OP to understand why their 3rd approach was slower than the 2nd, and hence answer their question.

@TheodorZoulias "and hence answer their question" Well, one of the five questions that they asked.

@Servy to be fair the OP has asked only three questions, not five. And all three are related to each other. Answering one of them is as good as answering all of them IMHO.

Sure they didn't include a question mark when asking for an in depth explanation of the internals of the two methods, but while it's not grammatically a question that doesn't really matter.  A "question" on SO is not obligated to be grammatically a question.  And while you vaguely imply what you might think is better, I certainly don't see you making an conclusive statements for that question.

@Servy I edited the answer and added direct answers to the OP's questions. I don't expect that the Parallel.ForEachAsync will be faster, and since this is the only criterion that the OP is interested for, I don't claim that it fulfills better this particular requirement compared to the alternative Task.WhenAll.

There's a bunch of misinformation in this thread, your issue isn't with some magical "balancer" that's supposedly part of Parallel.ForEach/Async (there is none), nor with its degrees of parallelism. In fact, you can run an unlimited amount of get requests on a single thread -- and you should know this, because that's what you're doing in your #2 example.
The reason why #3 is slower than #2, and why Theodor's unlimited degrees of parallelism thing seems to improve it, is simply due to how Linq works. That's right, your problem is a plain Linq problem, it has nothing to do with tasks, threads or http requests.
In #2, you call DownloadPhotoTask once for each thread, and then simply await their results with Task.WhenAll. In #3 however, you don't start any tasks, instead you rely on Parallel.ForEachAsync to call them for you, and it calls them in chunks of however many degrees of parallelism it has (hence the "fix" above).
But nothing stops you from doing something like starting all of the tasks (and thus their downloads) and then iterating over them:
var tasks = photos.Select(p => DownloadPhotoTask(p, httpClient)).ToArray();
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(tasks, async task =>
{
    await task;
    // do something interesting with the results
});


"In fact, you can run an unlimited amount of get requests on a single thread". -- I think that you mean launch, not run. As the caller you don't need any thread after the tasks are launched and they are in-flight. Nevertheless the asynchronous operations might use threads internally to do their job, and the caller has no control over it. It's an implementation detail, inaccessible to the caller.

Regarding your suggestion to launch the tasks externally to the Parallel.ForEachAsync, and only await then internally, what exactly is the point? The OP has not asked how to process the images in parallel. They have merely asked for guidance about how to download them as fast as possible. Hence your answer is off-topic IMHO.

Interesting that you claim ForEachAsync doesn't throttle work, and then go out of your way to prevent it from throttling work by starting the work ahead of time.  Throttling the starting of the tasks is one of ForEachAsync's primary features; it most certainly exists. "your problem is a plain Linq problem" None of the code in the question, nor any other answer, uses LINQ.

Blindy I am not sure that you have realized that your await Parallel.ForEachAsync(tasks suggestion is essentially an idiomatic version of the Task.WhenAll. And it is a flawed version, because in case a task is faulted the await Parallel.ForEachAsync(tasks will complete ASAP without awaiting the remaining tasks. These tasks will become fire-and-forget, which is a pretty bad idea in general. You don't want to lose track of the tasks you have created. You want to await all of them before doing other things, for example before retrying the same operation again.

"But nothing stops you from ..." - yes, C# syntax stops you.

For OP, if you want an actual answer to your question, and why your two approaches give different results, read up. If instead you just want to spawn a few hundred threads because of a flawed understanding of tasks, go with Theodor's answer. I'll leave it as is, people who don't understand tasks can feel free to downvote it.

@Blindy the Parallel.ForEachAsync configured for maximum parallelism will spawn hundreds of threads only if you give it CPU-bound work to do. If you give it I/O-bound work, it will use up to the soft limit of the ThreadPool, which is Environment.ProcessorCount (4 in my machine), and won't trigger the injection of more threads. If you think otherwise, please consider providing experimental evidence about the opposite. The size of the ThreadPool can be inspected at any moment with the ThreadPool.ThreadCount. Please share a link with a minimal runnable demo that supports your claims.

By "I/O-bound work" I mean asynchronous I/O, not blocking I/O. If you give it to do Thread.Sleep(5000);, it will surely cause the growth of the ThreadPool. If you give it await Task.Delay(5000);, it will not.
